# CSS problem with background color, online tutorial

Tags: html, css

I'm following an online tutorial for css and wrote the exact code as the instructor yet I'm unable to generate the desired output. I want the heading 'My Website' to have coral background while the output being generated applies coral background to the whole page.

```css
body{
     background-color:#f4f4f4;
     color:#555;
     font-family:sans-serif;
     font-size:16px;
     line-height:1.6em;
     margin:0;
    }
    
    .container{
     width:80%;
     margin:auto;
     overflow:hidden;
    }
    
    #main-header{
     background-color:coral;
     color:#fff;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>My Website</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <header id="main-header">
      <div class="container">
       <h1>My Website</h1>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want the heading 'My Website' to have coral background while the output being generated applies coral background to the whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my browsers your code even as-is works as you expect it to work. But there's one thing missing anyways. You don't have a closing tag for your `header`.

```css
body{
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    color:#555;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:1.6em;
    margin:0;
}

.container{
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#main-header{
    background-color:coral;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header id="main-header">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>My Website</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is a little bit unclear to me. What did you mean by heading? Did you main the h1 tag or the header tag. If your answer is h1 then I just gave a solution but if it is header then I think your code is generating the correct output in the snippet.

```css
body{
     background-color:#f4f4f4;
     color:#555;
     font-family:sans-serif;
     font-size:16px;
     line-height:1.6em;
     margin:0;
    }
    
    .container{
     width:80%;
     margin:auto;
     overflow:hidden;
    }
    
    #main-header h1{
     color:coral;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>My Website</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <header id="main-header">
      <div class="container">
       <h1>My Website</h1>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```